# How to mask more than 1 locator in playwright visual comparison

Tags: playwright

I would like to mask more than 1 locator in visual comparison using playwright ? How to do that ? Currently I can mask only 1 locator.

I tried more than 1 mask command, its not working

I would like to mask more than 1 locator in visual comparison using playwright ? How to do that ? Currently I can mask only 1 locator.

I tried more than 1 mask command, its not working

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please share the relevant snippet of your code where you are facing problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass an array of locators to [mask](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-pageassertions#page-assertions-to-have-screenshot-1-option-mask):

```
const maskedElement1 = await page.locator('element1); 
const maskedElement2 = await page.locator('element2); 
await expect(page).toHaveScreenshot({mask: [maskedElement1,maskedElement2]});
```